# Trouble displaying programmatically created views as topmost views?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIViewController (named Friends) with a tableview and I want to display views above the Controller's view when the user is offline. This is how I create my views

```
class func showOffline(host: UIViewController) {

    // showOffline image
    var disconnectedImage = UIImage(named: "offlineIconGrey")
    disconnectedImage = disconnectedImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: disconnectedImage)
    imageView.center = CGPoint(x: host.view.center.x,
                               y: host.view.center.y - imageView.frame.height/2)

    // showOffline Label
    let Label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    let labelText = "You appear to be offline \n Please connect to the internet"
    Label.center = CGPoint(x: host.view.center.x,
                           y: imageView.center.y + 3*imageView.frame.height/4)
    Label.numberOfLines = 0
    Label.text = labelText
    Label.textAlignment = .Center
    Label.font = UIFont(name: (Label.font?.fontName)!, size: 14.0)
    Label.sizeToFit()
    Label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    Label.lineBreakMode = .ByCharWrapping
    Label.frame.offsetInPlace(dx: -Label.frame.size.width/2, dy: 0)

    host.view.insertSubview(imageView, aboveSubview: host.view)
    host.view.insertSubview(Label, aboveSubview: host.view)

}
```

Now it is my understanding, that the host view (host.view) should be the topmost view as that is shown on my storyboard; however, when I call my showOffline function like so

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if !Reachability.isConnected() {
        state = .Offline

    } else {
        state = .Default
    }
}
```

where offline state calls,

```
General.showOffline(self)
```

like so

```
var state: State = .Default {
    didSet {
        switch (state) {
        case .Default:
            print("ViewMode = Default")
            //query = ParseHelper.allUsers(updateList)

        case .Search:
            let searchText = searchBar?.text ?? ""
            print(searchText)
            //query = ParseHelper.searchUsers(searchText, completionBlock:updateList)

        case .Offline:
            General.showOffline(self)
            searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = false
            query = nil
            users = [PFUser]() ?? []

            print("ViewMode = Offline")
        }
    }
}
```

the views do not appear as the topmost views unless I am returning to the view controller (Friends) from a show segue. Otherwise, navigating to that view controller does not show the labels when it should? Am I missing something? I have tried to fix the problem by placing the views above the tableview but in that case the math for centering the views is off, probably because I am not loading any cells and I have a footer view as a UIView. I also tried adding the views to the tableview's footer view, but that didn't work either. What I DON'T want is to add the views to the navigation controller's view as I do not want that behavior, though I will do that if I have no other option.

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqest.png)

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong or refer me to information that may help me fix my problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
host.view.insertSubview(imageView, aboveSubview: host.view)
```

This *cannot* work. You add a subview to host.view. The "aboveSubview" must be a subview of host.view. There are other methods for g
adding a subview.

Comment: Thanks. Calling host.view.addSubview(imageView) results in the exact same behavior I am experiencing using insert Subview. Adding a UIView parameter to my showOffline() and using host.view.insertSubview(imageView, aboveSubview: subview), then calling General.showOffline(self, self.tableView) also results in the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

When you call `insertSubview:aboveSubview:`, the view you give as second parameter must be a subview of the view you're inserting in. Here, it's the same view, so obviously it won't work.

Unless there are other views that should remain above the ones you're inserting, the easiest way is to just use `addSubview:`, which will make the new view topmost among the child of the target view.

Comment: but using addSubview results in the same behavior I am experiencing

Comment: Show us what you currently see. Also show us how changing the state calls showOffline.

Comment: What I currently see is what i linked without the views in the middle. Code was added, print statements are there for me to verify that changing state works. You can ignore the commented code

Comment: Use the view debugger (Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy or click on the "Debug View Hierarchy" button in the debug toolbar) to see if your views are effectively in the view hierarchy, and where.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Quite useful. I couldn't figure out why this happened but the offline views were loading underneath my tableView, even if I specified otherwise. So I simply set tableView alpha to 0 in offline mode since it results in desired behavior.